# How do I concatenate a dynamic string value using Groovy to JSON response after it's parsed to get a specific node value in JSON

Tags: json, groovy

[image]

```
   slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)
    log.info (slurperresponse.WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId)
```

The above code helps me get the node value `"WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId"` using Groovy. Below is the response.

```
{
   "TotalRecordCount": 1,
   "TotalPageCount": 1,
   "CurrentPage": 1,
   "BatchSize": 10,
   "WorkItems": [   {
      "WorkItemUId": "4336c111-7cd6-4938-835c-3ddc89961232",
      "WorkItemId": "20740900",
      "StackRank": "0",
      "WorkItemTypeUId": "00020040-0200-0010-0040-000000000000",
      "WorkItemExternalId": "79853"
}
```

I need to append the string `"WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId"` (being read from a excel file) and multiple other such nodes dynamically to `"slurperresponse"` to get the value of nodes rather than directly hard coding as `slurperresponse.WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId`..

Tried append and "+" operator but i get a compilation error. What other way can I do this?

Comment: could you please show your attempt with "+" operator? In a current form the question is not really clear...

Comment: Put it this way: log.info (slurperresponse.+".WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId")
Also tried $(slurperresponse.+".WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId"), but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slurperrsesponse` is an object its not a string that's why the concatenation does not work

Json Slurper creates an object out of the input string. This object is dynamic by nature, you can access it, you can add fields to it or alter the existing fields. Contatenation won't work here.

Here is an example:

```
import groovy.json.*

​def text = '{"total" : 2, "students" : [{"name": "John", "age" : 20}, {"name": "Alice", "age" : 21}] }'
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
json.total = 3 // alter the value of the existing field
json.city  = 'LA' // add a totally new field 
json.students[0].age++ // change the field in a list 
println json​
```

This yields the output:

```
[total:3, students:[[name:John, age:21], [name:Alice, age:21]], city:LA]
```

Now if I've got you right you want to add a new student dynamically and the input is a text that you've read from Excel. So here is the example:

```
json.students << new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"name" : "Tom", "age" : 25}')
// now there are 3 students in the list
```

**Update**

Its also possible to get the values without 'hardcoding' the property name:

```
// option 1
println json.city // prints 'LA'
// option 2
println json.get('city') // prints 'LA' but here 'city' can be a variable
// option 3
println json['city']     // the same as option 2
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your response. i am not adding anything to the json, i am reading the nodes i need to validate from excel file(as shown in attachment). 
so in your example, if i need to read the value json.city where the city part comes from excel. how can i do that?

Comment: Tried out the above method as mentioned by you. PFB response. 
def wi = "WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId"  

log.info slurperresponse.WorkItems[0].WorkItemExternalId  --> returns the required value

log.info slurperresponse['wi'] --->returns null

log.info slurperresponse.get('wi') --------> returns null

the last 2 methods don't seem to work in my case. not sure where i am going wrong

Comment: You need the full name including casing: println json.get('students')[0].get('name'). This prints 'john'. You need slurperresponse.get('WorkItems')[0].get('WorkItemExternalId')

Comment: slurperresponse.get('WorkItems')[0].get('WorkItemExternalId') seems to work fine. however, putting ('WorkItems')[0].get('WorkItemExternalId') into a variable fails. how do i put the data ('WorkItems')[0].get('WorkItemExternalId') into a variable?

Comment: You can't work with JSonSlurper like this. The result is an object with has properties and methods. If you want to constuct the "path" in string you can use JSonPath library https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath